# Custom response header columns in Firefox's Network Monitor

Tags: debugging, firefox-developer-tools

I am debugging caching on my website and have enabled some additional response headers indicating whether a request hit the cache and if not, an additional header with a reason. Through the built-in Network Monitor in Firefox I can check the response headers, but this is a tedious process for each request.

It is possible to add a response header as a column within Network Monitor however only common headers are available:

[image: Firefox Network Monitor showing the Response Headers column options]

Is it possible to add custom headers to this list such as `X-Cacheable`?

Comment: It looks like this list may be populated from [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/devtools/client/netmonitor/src/constants.js#l198). Unless there is a way to override this list through an `about:config` setting I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, that's currently (as of Firefox 68) not possible. There is already a request in [bug 1377013](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1377013)  to add a UI to manage custom response headers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow the issue.